# I cant insert in mysql from php

Tags: php, mysql

whats the solution for this problem Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

```
session_start();


$regValue1 = $_GET['un'];

$regValue2 = $_GET['pass'];

$regValue3 = $_GET['fn'] ;

$regValue4 = $_GET['ln'];

$regValue5 = $_GET['age'] ;

$regValue6 = $_GET['sex'];

$regValue7 = $_GET['em'] ;

echo "hello: ".$regValue3.".";


$servername = "localhost";
username = "root";
$password = "b4sonic";
$dbname = "blog";



$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO register(un,pass,fn,ln,age,sex,email)           VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
bind_param("sss",$regValue1,
$regValue2,$regValue3,$regValue4,$regValue5,$regValue6,$regValue7);

$stmt->execute();


echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

I have this code in php , i am trying to insert data to mysql but i face this problem Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables

Comment: sorry i forget  $stmt->  bind_param("sss",$regValue1,
$regValue2,$regValue3,$regValue4,$regValue5,$regValue6,$regValue7);

Comment: check your insert column field which is differ and also your missing put end quotes at end "INSERT INTO register(un,pass,fn,ln,age,sex,email) "

Comment: and how many `s`'s do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type string in your statement doesn't have enough type specifiers in it.

```
bind_param("sss",$regValue1,$regValue2,$regValue3,$regValue4,$regValue5,$regValue6,$regValue7);
```

says that you have type "sss" which only corresponds to 3 of the 7 variables you specified. You need to add types for the rest.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

> var1
>
> The number of variables and length of string types must match the parameters in the statement.

Comment: That's what jumped out at me first.

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $regValue1 , $regValue2, $regValue3  , $regValue4 , $regValue5, $regValue6 , $regValue7);

Answer (score 0):

The commands you are using are for using PDO to connect to an sql database and you are using mysqli. I gave an example using mysqli below that should work. The other option would be to change the connection to PDO type rather than mysqli.

```
<?php
session_start();


$regValue1 = $_GET['un'];

$regValue2 = $_GET['pass'];

$regValue3 = $_GET['fn'] ;

$regValue4 = $_GET['ln'];

$regValue5 = $_GET['age'] ;

$regValue6 = $_GET['sex'];

$regValue7 = $_GET['em'] ;

echo "hello: ".$regValue3.".";


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "b4sonic";
$dbname = "blog";



$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO register(un,pass,fn,ln,age,sex,email)".
        "VALUES (`$regValue1`,`$regValue2`,`$regValue3`,`$regValue4`,`$regValue5`,`$regValue6`,`$regValue7`)";
$conn->query($sql);

echo $conn->affected_rows. " new records created successfully";

$conn->close();
?>
```